What is the exact way to retrieve data from a Linked type API reponse without manually writing multiple requests?
I have a project on which I'm working and I'm using React on the frontend and the backend is built in Symfony + api-platform.
My problem is the following:
API calls return responses with a format which I'm not very familiar to.
Example: calling /api/towns/1 for a Town entity which is related to a Country entity gives
{ name : "New York",
   code : "NY",
   country : /api/countries/1
 }

So if I need the name or the code of the country I will have to make another call to /api/countries.
From what I researched I can use what is called vulcain and add a header { Preload : "/countries" }, but that does not work.
I tried it with axios and postman and I wasn't successful.
I also researched on adding #[ApiProperty(push: true)] on my entity definition in Symfony and it looks like this:
class Country
 {
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[ApiProperty(push: true)]`

But no success either
I don't really know how to approach the problem any help would be appreciated

If you always need your country name or code, you should avoid making a call every time but rather add it to your normalization groups #[Groups]
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ApiResource(normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['town']])]
class Town
{
    // ... 

    #[Groups('town')]
    public Country $country;

    // ...
}

Like that your answer will look directly like
{ 
   name : "New York",
   code : "NY",
   country : {
      name: "United States of America",
      code: "USA"
   }
 }


